# Getting any type in Unity Inspector

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

Edit: Added some more detail.

I am developing a SaveManager system for my games. Basicly what it should do is;

1) Gets the "ANY" user created Serializable class by Drag&Drop to inspector. (save data).

2) Writes that class to a file using either BinaryFormatter or XMLSerializer.

I want to be able to use it in my future games. So it should be save data class(type) independant (like serializers). I will use it like an asset, import the SaveManager, give serialized class as parameter, and let it do the rest. But as i said, it should be able to use any user created serialized class.

So the problem is, since that "serialized class" will be written by the user in the "game project" (not in the SaveManager project), and i don't have that "serialized" class type in my SaveManager project, i don't know how to make the SaveManager, reference the class from inspector.

So lets say i create this class in the game project (not in the SaveManager project)

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveData
{
    public string Name = "Name";
    public int Number = 5;
}
```

Now when i import the SaveManager project (asset) into my "game" project, i should be able to drag and drop the script to the SaveManager inspector and let it do the rest. Since BinaryFormatter works for every Serializable type, the name of the type is actually doesn't matter. I mean BinaryFormatter is type free as long as the type is serializable. I want to use that feature, and make the SaveManager type free too.

So in future if i want to use, say "MyNewSaveData" serialized class, "in an another game", i want to be able to drag and drop this to SaveManager inspector and let it do the rest.

Now the thing is, if i use

```
public object _SaveData;
```

in SaveManager script, unity inspector doesn't show it.

if i use

```
public Object _SaveData
```

it casts the user created type to an Object, and i lose the type i need.

I tried to use System.Type, but unity doesn't show it too.

Basicly what i want to do is, get "any" serialized class as reference. Like

```
public SerializedClass _SaveData;
```

or something like

```
public Script _SaveData;
```

That reference should accept "any" serialized class. Gets it's type, then casts it to that type.

When i use

```
public Object _SaveData
```

if i use _SaveData.GetType(), i get the type the "user created". 
I have the type, in my hands, but i can't cast Object to that type. I don't know how to use that type for casting.

What ever i do, it either doesn't show up in inspector, or it casted to another type and i lose the data.

What should i do?

Comment: Side note: I suspect you are asking about Unity3d (game framework), not Unity (dependency injection framework) - if true make sure to update tags.

Comment: when you use the `public Object _SaveData` and then you call `_SaveData.GetType()` what is the output?

Comment: @Ideae I get the type i want. But i don't know how to use it to cast. I tried;
Type type = _SaveData.GetType();
And here i get the type. But how do i use it? I cant use (type)_SaveData, there is no usage like that.
Convert.ChangeType(object, type) doesn't work too, since i can't cast Unity Object to System object.
So here i am, with the type in my hand but no way to use it.

Comment: I just tried to explicitly cast it from Object to object, and it worked. `object o = _SaveData;` It's just boxing it in the object. You shouldn't need to even do that, you should be able to drop the Object directly into the XMLSerializer Serialize method. In fact, the type is not required at all. The only thing you need is a way to reset the reference where the original SaveData object lived after you Deserialize (to load a game).

Comment: The reason for that is because the Deserialize method in the XMLSerializer always creates a new object, and if you just reset the reference inside the SaveManager to the Object, it won't update the original object (from where you dragged it in). So you'll need another way to reset the reference (maybe by keeping it in the same spot always, or holding a reference to the object that stores the SaveData).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like this, because there is no way you can drag'n'drop a [Serializable] class in the inspector, it has no representation in terms of project management. Also you can only drag'n'drop an instance anyway, not the class itself. You could serialize a reference to a MonoScript, but that's editor-only and I'm not sure what good it would do you.

You should try using a ScriptableObject maybe, or even provide a base abstract type in your SaveManager project, and require that your game project derives from that.

But either way, I'm not sure I understand exactly how you want to proceed: once you have your type, what will you do with it? your game still needs to set the actual data, decide when to read/write that data, etc etc, so how can you just drag'n'drop & expect the manager to just figure out everthing by itself?

Best I could see is your game sets the data, then calls SaveManager.Save(myData), or .Load(myData), and then your manager saves that instance to binary or XML or whatever.

BTW I'd recommend JSON, there are lots of good Unity-compatible libs out there. Binary is too risky (you change the format and you can kiss your saves goodbye, or enjoy the headache of converting between versions), and XML is too verbose.